# vb.net How to make Fixed width Label?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, label

[image]

Like the image above, I want to make a certain Label with fixed width without any scrollbar. It means, actually, the width of Label is changed with the size of outer Panel, however, the height of the Label is just fit to display the whole text inside.

If I set the AutoSize property to True, I can't set the width of the Label.

Thank you!

---

The important thing is the '...XYZ' part that the HEIGHT of the Label is just fit to the end of the text. No more space or no less space.

I want to make the height of the Label to be just fit to the text inside. The width is changing to fit the width of Form size, which is intended, while the height of the Label is constant, which is NOT.

Comment: Check Anchor property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a trick for the solution. (or maybe this is an ordinary solution)

I set the AutoSize property to true then wrapped the Label within a FlowLayoutPanel.

I anchored the Flowable Panel TOP,LEFT and RIGHT as well as set the AutoSize to true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 'Autosize' to false and then use the 'Anchor' property to pin the right side of the label (as well as the left and top which are already pinned by default).

Comment: Like the other comment, I anchored the Label to TOP, LEFT, RIGHT so that the width is automatically changed. But the HEIGHT of the Label won't that not the whole text is displayed with long text. I don't want to fix the height but rather want to make it flexible. Thanks!

Comment: @klados Then you will also want to set 'multiline' to true and the bottom anchor. At that point you could also skip the anchor settings altogether and use the 'dock' property to just make it fill the panel.

Comment: basically the multiline property of the Label is set to true. I am wondering how can I make the height of the Label to be just fit to the text inside. The width is changing to fit the width of Form size, while the height of the Label is constant.

Comment: I mean the width of Label should be changing according to the width of Form size, while the height of Label should be changing according to the end of the text. (to display whole text, but without any surplus space)

Answer (score 0):

The [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property from MSDN

> Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically
>   resized as its parent control is resized. Anchoring a control to its
>   parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same
>   position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent
>   control is resized.

As you explain that this label is inside a panel, then you need to set the Anchor property also for the Panel inside the Form (the object that actually resizes itself). You could also look at the similar [Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

Comment: Yes, I anchored the Label to TOP, LEFT, RIGHT so that the width is automatically changed. But the HEIGHT of the Label won't that not the whole text is displayed with long text. I don't want to fix the height but rather want to make it flexible. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the text to be wrapped to the next line if not enough width to display all the content?

Comment: yes that's right! I want the text to be wrapped. But the point is that I want the height of the Label to be just fit to the actual height of the text displayed. The Label is successfully stretched horizontally, while the height is fixed.

Comment: I mean the width of Label should be changing according to the width of Form size, while the height of Label should be changing according to the end of the text. (to display whole text, but without any surplus space)

Comment: I suggest to take a look at this discussion and the code example [GrowLabel class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97c18a1d-729e-4a68-8223-0fcc9ab9012b/automatically-wrap-text-in-label?forum=winforms)